# Append a button with onClick function - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append this html on a table with jQuery but the onClick part is giving me some trouble

This is the JS code:

```
 $('table#devel tbody').append('<tr id="'+response[0].categoryid+'">' +
 '<td><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onClick="alert('+response[0].recid+',\'deleteCategory\','+response[0].categoryid+');">Delete</button></td></tr>');
```

The append works fine but when I press the button the only thing that is being shown in the alert box is the first value and none of the other two.

Comment: see the generated source

Comment: Type `alert(1,2,3);` into your console. What appears? That would be your problem. Alert does not take comma separated values.

Comment: I know what this does @epascarello. consider alert(1+',2,'+3)

Comment: @geo, but you do not have `+` ! Your code renders with no plus....

Comment: And if you are calling it the other problem you have is if the parameters are a string, they need to be wrapped in quotes... Simple inspection of the html with the console should show you that problem. OR add events without using inline code...

Comment: i got it `onClick="dlte('+response[0].recid+',\'deleteCategory\','+response[0].categoryid+');"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commas are throwing things off. You should enclose what you want in the alert box in quotes:

```
$('table#devel tbody').append('<tr id="'+response[0].categoryid+'">' + '<td><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onClick="alert(\''+response[0].recid+',deleteCategory,'+response[0].categoryid+'\');">Delete</button></td></tr>');
```

Not sure what `deleteCategory` is but that should be enough to get you started.

Comment: the delete category is not a variable though

Comment: I used alert because I thought I was going to simplify my answer. the alert should be the name of a function that takes 3 arguments. The middle one is a string

Comment: Use something besides "alert" for your name, then - it's reserved by Javascript.

Comment: I know I just wanted to alert the arguments, check if they are correct and then sub the alert with the actual name...

Comment: Then make a separate alert for each argument. You can't call an alert like that.

Comment: you were right. Testing with alert wasn't a bright idea. `onClick="dlte('+response[0].recid+',\'deleteCategory\','+response[0].categoryid+');"` That is what i was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alert() don't support multiply parameters like you use (or you have a problem with escaping).

change it to something like:

```
"alert(\''+ response[0].recid + ', deleteCategory: '+response[0].categoryid+'\');"
```